# Run-Time error '6' Overflow

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not sure why, but I am receiving a run time error when entering a certain ID number: 3038776336 on the popup. I have tried changing the variable from a string to Long but that did not work. What else am I missing?

```
Range("BM1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "I/O"
lngLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim Account As String
ID = InputBox("ID #")

Dim Cont
For Cont = 2 To lngLastRow
    If Cells(Cont, 10) = CLng(ID) Then
       Cells(Cont, 65).FormulaR1C1 = "Outbound"
    Else
       Cells(Cont, 65).FormulaR1C1 = "Inbound"
    End If
Next Cont
```

Comment: Is `lngLastRow` declared somewhere?

Comment: no but I did try that and that did not seem to help

Comment: I did find that if I change the CLng to CStr that worked so it may just be a mismatch but it is strange that it worked on other numbers but not this one

Comment: Why does that surprise you that it overflows?  The maximum value for a long is 2147483647.

Comment: Declaring your variables is always going to help. Stick `Option Explicit` at the top of every single module, declare every single variable you're ever using. *Then* ask for help. Code with undeclared variables is just *asking* for bugs to happen. And yeah, a long integer is 32 bit in VBA, so either use a `Double` if you *really* need a numeric value, or convert it to a string.

Comment: was unaware there was a max number. What would you suggest I use?

Comment: [Documentation.SO](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3418/data-types-and-limits#t=201612052228165353559), for a start.

Comment: What is option explicit mean this is new to me

Comment: It forces you to declare your stuff. Any undeclared variable and VBA will refuse to compile and run. That's step 1. Without `Option Explicit`, VBA will happily compile and run with typos and other kinds of stupid errors that waste everyone's time. Declare. Your. Variables. All the time.

Comment: main reason I was using the CLng was to have it ignore any leading zeros. Thanks for the link that looks helpful

Comment: If you really need to remove leading zeros, try `Int(ID)`, but strictly speaking, you should check that it is numeric first, with `If IsNumeric(ID) Then`

Comment: Note that even `Int(ID)` should only be used to the `Double` precision limit of 9007199254740992.

Comment: I think INT(ID) will do, should I have also done DIM Account as Integer instead of string?

Comment: Your code doesn't use the variable `Account`, so it probably doesn't matter what it is declared as.  (If you want to use it to store the numeric value of `ID`, declare it as a `Double`.)

Answer (score 0):

1. dim ID as double
2. remove CLng from "If Cells(Cont, 10) = CLng(ID) Then"

Answer (score 0):

Runtime Error 6 is an overflow. Your value is greater than the maximum for a `Long`. Based on what you're doing, you don't need to convert the value to a `Long`. Just try leaving it as a `String`.

```
Dim ID As String
ID = InputBox("ID #")
...
If StrComp(Cells(Cont, 10).Text,ID,vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
...
```